# What kind of join to use on SQL tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables that contain data on movies. They are called appalling, average and outstanding. They all have columns title_types, genre, year and rating. I am trying to join all 3 tables into a new table called facts, using this hint:

Think carefully about the join types for this
query to avoid losing records from the individual tables.

My initial thought is to join all tables using a full outer join, and doing some digging, this was my code

```
CREATE TABLE Facts as 
SELECT Appalling.title_type, Average.title_type, Outstanding.title_type
FROM Appalling 
FULL OUTER JOIN Average ON Appalling.title_type = Average.title_type
FULL OUTER JOIN Outstanding ON Appalling.title_type = Outstanding.title_type;
```

However I am not sure if this is the smartest way to join all tables. Any help is appreciated. I believe the final output should look like such:

```
title_type | genre  | year | appalling | average | outstanding
movie        drama    1992    1            NULL      NULL
tv           comedy   2001    NULL          15       NULL
short        drama    2014    NULL         NULL      17
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but both the table design and the join requirement seem really strange. What does the `title_types` column contain?

Comment: @Matt Title types are like video games, movies, tv series etc.

Comment: OK, and how do you want the final output to look, and by that I mean, what columns do you want to select?

Comment: @Matt I'm guessing I need all columns, aka the title types, genre, year and rating

Comment: I think your design is kind of flawed. You shouldn't need a join here because you shouldn't need three tables `appalling`, `average` and `outstanding`. You need one table, `movies`, and an extra column `quality_rating`. If you're trying to merge the three tables use `UNION ALL`. Please edit your question to add sample data and expected results.

Comment: I agree with Matt and Craig: this seems like a horrible design. You only need a single table

Comment: @CraigRinger Unfortunately I did not pick this design, and will have to make do with what I have

Comment: @CuriousStudent TBH I'd create a view that `UNION ALL`'d them together with a constant "quality_rating" column  for each union term, then query that.

Comment: @CraigRinger i actually ran into a small problem with the union all, in that I lose the distinguishing factor of whether a movie is appalling, average or outstanding. To clarify - before each table had a column called appalling average or outstanding, and that column contained counts. With the union all i can no longer distinguish them. Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: @CuriousStudent `SELECT 'awful' AS rating, awful.* FROM awful UNION ALL SELECT 'average', average.* FROM average ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like extremely bad data schema design.

You should be using 1 table with simply a column that indicates if a movie is average, apalling or outstanding.

But, failing that and if the other columns are similar in both tables, you can use `UNION ALL`: (Updated so you can still distinguish.

```
CREATE TABLE Facts -- Data Types are for demo purposes, I have no idea what you use, use the appropriate data type yourself
( 
column_types varchar(500), 
title varchar(500), 
genre varchar(500), 
year int, 
rating int,
ratingType varchar(500)
);

INSERT INTO Facts (column_types, title, genre, year, rating, ratingType)
(
SELECT a.column_types, a.title, a.genre, a.year, a.rating, 'Average' AS ratingType FROM Average AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT ap.column_types, ap.title, ap.genre, ap.year, ap.rating, 'Appalling' AS ratingType FROM Appalling AS ap
UNION ALL
SELECT o.column_types, o.title, o.genre, o.year, o.rating, 'Outstanding' AS ratingType FROM Outstanding AS o
);
```

Comment: I agree. One snag I ran into with the union all is that my columns no longer distinguish between appalling, average and outstanding. Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: I edited my main post, do you think the design would be better structured that way?

Comment: @CuriousStudent I edited my answer to keep an indicator of which table it came from. As to your question, what is the table supposed to actually do? Does it save how many people rated what as outstanding, average, appalling etc?